# Which is the extension build order in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have these extensions in "extensioninfo.xml":

```
<extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/ext-commerce/b2bapprovalprocess"/>
<extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/ext-commerce/b2bcommerce"/>
<extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/ext-template/b2bstore"/>
<extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/ext-commerce/basecommerce"/>
<extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/ext-content/bmecat"/>
```

How are these extensions built? Is there any order if I have them in the same "extensioninfo.xml" file? Will "b2bapprovalprocess" be built before "b2bcommerce", "b2bcommerce" before "b2bstore" and so on... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is defined by dependencies of extensions using requires-extension in extensions' extensioninfo.xml.

If C requires-extension B, and B requires-extension A, then the order is A, B, C.

If C requires-extension A, and B requires-extension A, then the order can be A, B, C or A, C, B. i.e. If 2 or more extensions are on the same level, then the order may be random at that level.

In the example code below from `acceleratorcms` extension, we can be sure that `cms2lib` or `acceleratorservices` will be processed first before `acceleratorcms`. However, we cannot be sure which one will be first: `cms2lib` or `acceleratorservices`.

```
<extensioninfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="extensioninfo.xsd">
    <extension abstractclassprefix="Generated" classprefix="AcceleratorCms" managername="AcceleratorCmsManager" managersuperclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.extension.Extension" name="acceleratorcms">              
        <requires-extension name="cms2lib"/>                
        <requires-extension name="acceleratorservices"/>                
        <coremodule generated="true" manager="de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.jalo.AcceleratorCmsManager" packageroot="de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms"/>            
    </extension>
</extensioninfo>
```